Extraction of Metadata using Bosch VideoSDK
Using Bosch Configuration manager :camera :-DINION 5100i IR
i dont know,how to display metadata but let me tell you what i have done with Configuration manager.
connect to camera>>recording >>scheduled the recording>>start recording>>VCA>>setting profile#1>>Analysis type: IVA PRO TRAFFIC>> Traffic tracking 3D>>start VCA recording.
Then after i stop the recording let suppose after 5minutes...i put for 15 minutes but  5mins is enough for me now to test the recording is working and getting  metadata in .mp4 and .ind file.
while recoring VCA shows or detect person and there path where they are moving  etc...
Now want to extract the metadata,to get the information present in that video.How can i do ?
I was told to use VideoSDK - but i don't understand anything form it.

